# how to parse my xml string using NSXmlParser?

Tags: xml-parsing

hi i am new to iOS developement.
following is my response by web sevice in xml formart.how can i parse this string by using xml parser.
plz help me

```
<registration><status>3</status></registration>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using these method you can complete your xml parsing.Try These method.

```
 -(NSMutableArray *)parseXML:(NSString *)data
 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:    (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```